# How do I add a table of content automatically on an AMP page hosted over Blogger?

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to add automatic table of content on my AMP page mrabhisheksuman.com (just like used on every post of amp.dev).
Can anyone help in this regard. I will be very thankful to him.